# Закон, указ и т.д. - прописные буквы

Tags: прописная-строчная

Я часто вижу в официальных текстах, когда слова "Закон", "Указ", "Приказ", а еще "Правительство" пишутся с большой буквы.
Честно говоря, не вижу ни одной причины писать эти слова именно так. Название законов-указов-приказов - это да, безусловно, с прописной и в кавычках. А еще "правительство" - почему?
Правильно ли все это, или мы видим просто попытку авторов текстов "прогнуться" перед оным правительством?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Правительство" с заглавной объяснить трудно.
Закон, Указ и т.д. могут выступать в качестве условных имен собственных в официальном стиле речи (в юридических документах и т.п.) - в тех случаях, когда выше по тексту есть или подразумевается фраза типа *"далее именуемый Указ"*. Но нигде более.   
Иначе это или вечное стремление российского чиновника к подобострастию, или неудачное подражение английскому.

Comment: Правительство РФ - это имя собственное, поэтому первое слово пишется с прописной буквы. Только в качестве имени собственного оно присутствует в официальных документах. В других случаях может иметь нарицательное значение.

Comment: Разумеется, в таком виде - да. *Хотя это никак не отменяет предположения о подобострастии, почему-то правительства других стран привилегией быть именем собственным не наделяются.*  
Но вопрос-то даже не об этом. Там просто о "правительстве", без РФ.

Comment: Правительство Москвы - это также имя собственное, название органа управления. Область применения - официальные документы. Если оно используется в других случаях, то это, скорее, не подобострастие, а неграмотность чиновников.

Comment: Не вижу причин считать его собственным. Ни в официальных документах, ни где еще. Чем оно лучше **"Мусоросортировочного Департамента  при заборостроительном цехе макароносверлиной фабрики"**?

Comment: Вот! Мне тоже всегда казалось, что все эти "Указы" и "Законы" с прописной буквы - это раболепство.

Answer (score 1):

Поделюсь собственными соображениями. Заглавная буква в русском языке порой выполняет функцию определённого артикля, то есть указывает, что речь идёт о конкретном объекте. Приведу пример.

> > Правительство – это система, управляющая государством или сообществом.
> >
> > **A** government is the system by which a state or community is governed.

Здесь говорится о правительстве как о неком отвлечённом объекте, в целом.

> > Сейчас Правительство переходит к карательным мерам.
> >
> > Now **the** government passes to repression.

Здесь говорится о правительстве какой-то конкретной страны.

Answer (score 1):

Такие слова, как "указ, закон, правительство" могут писаться как с прописной, так и со строчной буквы.

Например: Указ Президента РФ  "О неотложных мерах социальной поддержки ...". В тексте самого документа слово "Указ" будет писаться с прописной буквы как первое слово названия документа: "Настоящий Указ вступает в силу ...". Также прописная буква пишется в  официальных названиях, например: Принят Указ Президента РФ  «О неотложных мерах...". В других случаях слово "указ" является нарицательным существительным и пишется со строчной буквы: "В указе дается ряд поручений...".

Также: Состав Правительства Москвы - в официальных документах. Но: программа правительства Москвы - неофициальное название.